# Finding the xpath of a certain div

Tags: objective-c, ios, xpath, hpple

I'm using the hpple library to get the content of a certain div on a webpage.

Usage:

```
NSData* data = [trimmedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//div[@id='container']"]; 
TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *string = [element content];
NSLog(string);
```

Now I'm thinking that should fill the string *string with the content of the div container?

I'm getting this error and crash:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Now I guess this is because it hasn't filled the array with anything from that div? One reason being it hasn't found parsed the link I gave it, but its not crashed on xpathParser so I'm guessing its parsed it fine?

Which tells me its my xpath in this line which is wrong:

```
searchWithXPathQuery:@"//div[@id='content']"];
```

Can anyone help me find the xpath for the div below the text "I need all this text below:" (I have provided all the divs above it. (it's the last div on the page of html)

```
<body class="html not-front not-logged-in no-sidebars page-node page-node- page-node-68 node-type-article" >
<div id="container">
    <section id="main" role="main">
        <header>
            <div id="logo"><a href="/"><img src="/sites/all/themes/bmco/images/logo.gif" /></a></div>
            <nav class="navigation" id="mainmenu">
                  <div class="region region-menupanel">
    <div id="block-superfish-1" class="block block-superfish">


  <div class="content">
    <ul id="superfish-1" class="sf-menu main-menu sf-horizontal sf-style-default sf-total-items-7 sf-parent-items-5 sf-single-items-2"><li id="menu-566-1" class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-1 sf-no-children"><a href="/" title="" class="sf-depth-1 ">home</a></li><li id="menu-567-1" class="middle even sf-item-2 sf-depth-1 sf-total-children-6 sf-parent-children-0 sf-single-children-6 menuparent"><a href="/company" title="data centre design and build" class="sf-depth-1  menuparent">company</a><ul><li id="menu-395-1" class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/case-studies" class="sf-depth-2 ">case studies</a></li><li id="menu-393-1" class="middle even sf-item-2 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/news" class="sf-depth-2 ">news</a></li><li id="menu-608-1" class="middle odd sf-item-3 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/downloads" title="" class="sf-depth-2 ">downloads</a></li><li id="menu-572-1" class="middle even sf-item-4 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/meet-team" class="sf-depth-2 ">meet the team</a></li><li id="menu-609-1" class="middle odd sf-item-5 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/working-you" title="2bm is committed to being a responsible business.  We aim to ensure that, in everything we do, we meet the highest standards of business ethics and conduct." class="sf-depth-2 ">working with you</a></li><li id="menu-607-1" class="last even sf-item-6 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/blog" title="" class="sf-depth-2 ">blog</a></li></ul></li><li id="menu-573-1" class="middle odd sf-item-3 sf-depth-1 sf-total-children-12 sf-parent-children-0 sf-single-children-12 menuparent"><a href="/design-and-build" title="" class="sf-depth-1  menuparent">design and build</a><ul><li id="menu-583-1" class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/design-and-build/access-and-security" class="sf-depth-2 ">access and security</a></li><li id="menu-577-1" class="middle even sf-item-2 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/design-and-build/cabling" class="sf-depth-2 ">cabling</a></li><li id="menu-585-1" class="middle odd sf-item-3 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/design-and-build/clinical-cleaning" class="sf-depth-2 ">clinical cleaning</a></li><li id="menu-580-1" class="middle even sf-item-4 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/design-and-build/cooling" class="sf-depth-2 ">cooling</a></li><li id="menu-579-1" class="middle odd sf-item-5 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/design-and-build/electrical-supply" class="sf-depth-2 ">electrical supply</a></li><li id="menu-582-1" class="middle even sf-item-6 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/design-and-build/fire-supression" title="Data Centre Fire Suppression and Detection" class="sf-depth-2 ">fire suppression</a></li><li id="menu-574-1" class="middle odd sf-item-7 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/design-and-build/flooring" class="sf-depth-2 ">flooring</a></li><li id="menu-586-1" class="middle even sf-item-8 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/design-and-build/maintenance" class="sf-depth-2 ">maintenance</a></li><li id="menu-581-1" class="middle odd sf-item-9 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/design-and-build/power-monitoring" class="sf-depth-2 ">power monitoring</a></li><li id="menu-578-1" class="middle even sf-item-10 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/design-and-build/project-management" class="sf-depth-2 ">project management</a></li><li id="menu-584-1" class="middle odd sf-item-11 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/design-and-build/racking" class="sf-depth-2 ">racking</a></li><li id="menu-575-1" class="last even sf-item-12 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/design-and-build/room-construction-and-layout" class="sf-depth-2 ">room construction and layout</a></li></ul></li><li id="menu-588-1" class="middle even sf-item-4 sf-depth-1 sf-total-children-3 sf-parent-children-0 sf-single-children-3 menuparent"><a href="/monitoring" title="" class="sf-depth-1  menuparent">monitoring</a><ul><li id="menu-590-1" class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/monitoring/environmental-monitoring" class="sf-depth-2 ">environmental monitoring</a></li><li id="menu-592-1" class="middle even sf-item-2 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/monitoring/innovative-cabling" class="sf-depth-2 ">innovative cabling</a></li><li id="menu-589-1" class="last odd sf-item-3 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/monitoring/sensorium-software" class="sf-depth-2 ">sensorium software</a></li></ul></li><li id="menu-587-1" class="middle odd sf-item-5 sf-depth-1 sf-total-children-10 sf-parent-children-0 sf-single-children-10 menuparent"><a href="/room-and-rack-infrastructure" title="" class="sf-depth-1  menuparent">room and rack</a><ul><li id="menu-598-1" class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/room-and-rack-infrastructure/iec-lock" class="sf-depth-2 ">IEC lock</a></li><li id="menu-594-1" class="middle even sf-item-2 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/room-and-rack-infrastructure/kvm" class="sf-depth-2 ">KVM</a></li><li id="menu-597-1" class="middle odd sf-item-3 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/room-and-rack-infrastructure/ups" class="sf-depth-2 ">UPS</a></li><li id="menu-576-1" class="middle even sf-item-4 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/design-and-build/airflow-management" class="sf-depth-2 ">airflow management</a></li><li id="menu-595-1" class="middle odd sf-item-5 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/room-and-rack-infrastructure/aisle-containment" class="sf-depth-2 ">aisle containment</a></li><li id="menu-599-1" class="middle even sf-item-6 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/room-and-rack-infrastructure/clinical-cleaning" class="sf-depth-2 ">clinical cleaning</a></li><li id="menu-593-1" class="middle odd sf-item-7 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/room-and-rack-infrastructure/floor-tiles" class="sf-depth-2 ">floor tiles</a></li><li id="menu-596-1" class="middle even sf-item-8 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/room-and-rack-infrastructure/power-strips" class="sf-depth-2 ">power strips</a></li><li id="menu-600-1" class="middle odd sf-item-9 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/room-and-rack-infrastructure/racks" class="sf-depth-2 ">racks</a></li><li id="menu-601-1" class="last even sf-item-10 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/room-and-rack-infrastructure/security" class="sf-depth-2 ">security</a></li></ul></li><li id="menu-591-1" class="middle even sf-item-6 sf-depth-1 sf-total-children-5 sf-parent-children-0 sf-single-children-5 menuparent"><a href="/imeter" title="The 2bm iMeter - data centre power monitoring" class="sf-depth-1  menuparent">iMeter</a><ul><li id="menu-604-1" class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/imeter/zero-downtime-0" title="data centre power monitoring" class="sf-depth-2 ">Zero Downtime</a></li><li id="menu-602-1" class="middle even sf-item-2 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/imeter/why-imeter" title="power and environmental monitoring" class="sf-depth-2 ">Why iMeter</a></li><li id="menu-610-1" class="middle odd sf-item-3 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/imeter/how-it-works-0" title="power and environmental monitoring" class="sf-depth-2 ">How it works</a></li><li id="menu-603-1" class="middle even sf-item-4 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/imeter/imeter-monitoring-software" title="power and environmental monitoring software" class="sf-depth-2 ">Monitoring software</a></li><li id="menu-611-1" class="last odd sf-item-5 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children"><a href="/imeter/case-studies" title="University of Nottingham opts for 2bm iMeter power and environmental monitoring solution" class="sf-depth-2 ">Case Studies</a></li></ul></li><li id="menu-565-1" class="last odd sf-item-7 sf-depth-1 sf-no-children"><a href="/contact-us" class="sf-depth-1 ">contact us</a></li></ul>  </div>
</div>
  </div>
            </nav>
            <div id="headerimagepanel">
                <div id="headerimage"><img src="/sites/all/themes/bmco/images/newsheader.jpg" /></div>
                <div id="headermenu"><nav id="hmenupanel" class="navigation"></nav></div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <nav id="menupanel">
            <nav id="archivemenu" class="navigation">  <div class="region region-archivemenublog">
    <div id="block-views-blog-archive-block" class="block block-views">

    <h2>Monthly archive</h2>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="view view-blog-archive view-id-blog_archive view-display-id-block view-dom-id-a384fd1f4628f80c660e22d4df3b4779">



      <div class="view-content">
      <div class="item-list">
  <ul class="views-summary">
      <li><a href="/blog/archive/201208">August 2012</a>
              (1)
          </li>
    </ul>
</div>
    </div>






</div>  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</nav>  
        </nav>
        <div id="contentpanel">
                                        <h2 class="title" id="page-title">How secure are your racks? </h2>

              <div class="region region-content">
    <div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system">


  <div class="content">
    <div id="node-68" class="node node-article node-promoted clearfix" about="/blog/how-secure-are-your-racks" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document">


    I need all this text below:

  <div class="content">
    <div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded"><p>Data centre security is a big issue – especially for co-location centres hosting multiple racks for multiple, often competing, clients. Yet whilst security to access the data centre can often be impressive, individual rack level security is often inadequate. Given the number of in-house staff and external engineers, from cablers to storage and server providers, traipsing through a data centre on a near daily basis, poor rack level security is a potential risk.</p>
<p>According to a recent survey conducted by Lieberman Software, 42 percent of IT staff can get unauthorised access to their organisation’s most sensitive information – including the CEO’s private documents. The failing is blamed on management’s naivety when it comes to understanding just how much privileged access their IT departments actually have.</p>
<p>The fact that most racks are secured only with standard handles using a manual key, bears out this survey. Easily broken or bypassed, these locks provide minimal corporate protection; they offer no access control or audit trail of activity. Given the huge ongoing investment in data centres - during 2011-2012, the UK invested an estimated $3.35 billion in data centres; the second highest spending of any country, according to the Datacentre Dynamics Global Industry Census 2011 - extending standard access control techniques to the data centre racks is an important step.</p>
<p>Companies can opt for a rack specific key, combination locks or key cards that are IP enabled to allow an organisation to impose strict control over the time/day an individual is allowed to access the rack. Using standard access control software, all activity is recorded and audited, providing the organisation with a complete list of those who have accessed the racks.</p>
<p>For organisations, this approach adds control and addresses one important aspect of the internal threat. For co-location sites, rack level security removes the need to cage off client specific rack space areas freeing up space that can be used for more racks, delivering a return on investment, as well as improved client security.</p>
</div></div></div>  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** : Based on the full HTML, I changed the XPathQuery

```
TFHppleElement *element  = [xpathParser peekAtSearchWithXPathQuery:@"//div[@id='node-68']"]; 
// Use peekAtSearchWithXPathQuery as there is only one vdiv with this id so you directly get the element (the function grabs the first element that corresponds to the XPath query)
```

Then to get the text, iterate through its children

```
-(NSString*) getStringForTFHppleElement:(TFHppleElement *)element {

    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString new];

    // Iterate recursively through all children
    for (TFHppleElement *child in [element children])
        [result appendString:[self getStringForTFHppleElement:child]];

    // Hpple creates a <text> node when it parses texts
    if ([element.tagName isEqualToString:@"text"])
        [result appendString:element.content];

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this although its not the last "content" on the page its just the last in my question as I didnt want to paste loads of html. How would I get the text from the 4th "content" class?

Comment: If you know you want the 4th div, just do `element = [elements objectAtIndex:3]`

Comment: after 6 days of pulling my hair out I still cant get this text in the html into a string, if I link you to the whole html source code could you help me get to the div with the main text in? (mentioned above?) http://pastebin.com/sPV7AeqY is the full html. after debugging it looks like the nsarray elements array is empty?

Comment: edited my answer and tested it, it works fine ! (just some breaklines to remove and you are good to go)